# Adding "mscorlib.dll" causing errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, assemblies

I added "mscorlib.dll" reference to VS2017 project to fix an issue.
I added the following line to my .csproj file to refer mscorlib

```
    <ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="mscorlib">
    <!-- Replace with whatever your path to mscorlib is -->
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

After I add that reference I started getting errors that I'm missing predefined types like in the below, can some one let me know what is the cause for this.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p44Hx.jpg)

Comment: That might the wrong fix then. What was your original issue that you were trying to solve?

Comment: @Rup, one of the function on my .cs file couldn't identify "Cryptography" in the name space "System.Security", So, I added the "mscorlib.dll" explicitly in .csproj file which is causing the issue as mentioned before